# How to avoid the conflict between the blur effect of Backdrop and the splash effect of TabBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

```dart
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Tab> get tabs => ["Intro", "Flow", "Market"]
      .map((e) => Tab(
            text: e,
          ))
      .toList(growable: false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Layout(
      title: "Title",
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          _buildHeader(),
          _buildStickyBar(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHeader() {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(child: Image.assets("some.jpg"), top: 40, bottom: -20, right: -20),
          BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 40.0, sigmaY: 40.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.06),
              ),
              child: Text("effect")),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildStickyBar() {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      floating: true,
      delegate: SliverPersistentHeaderEx(//some simple impl
        minHeight: 32,
        maxHeight: 32,
        child: TabBar(
          controller: tabController, //it's not the point
          tabs: tabs),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The theme used is a black theme, and the splash is white.

So, the *blur* effect and *splash* effect will conflict. In detail, the splash effect of TabBar will **spread** to the upper widget(stack, in this case). If you remove `withOpacity`, the blur effect will be *lost*, but the diffusion problem will be solved.

I want to keep those effects. How can I limit the *splash* effect of the TaBbar to only appear in the TabBar?

[effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njroR.gif)

Answer (score 0):

As documentation says:

> The filter will be applied to all the area within its parent or
> ancestor widget's clip. If there's no clip, the filter will be applied
> to the full screen.

Try to wrap your BackdropFilter with ClipRect

```
ClipRect(
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 40.0, sigmaY: 40.0),
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.06),
              ),
              child: Text("effect")),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Doing this hasn't changed anything. Same behavior